# JsonConvert.SerializeObject adds default Result name

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services, json.net

Whenever i am trying to Serialize  the Object with JsonConvert.SerializeObject it adds a default array name as "d"

```
        json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
        {
            resultsets = new List<Result>()
                {
                    new Result { id = 1, value = "ABC", info = "ABC" },
                    new Result { id = 2, value = "JKL", info = "JKL" },
                    new Result { id = 3, value = "GSG", info = "DYU" }
                }
        });

        return json;
```

The Json responce is

```
{
   "d": "{"resultsets":[{"id":1,"value":"ABC","info":"ABC"},{"id":2,"value":"JKL","info":"JKL"},{"id":3,"value":"GSG","info":"DYU"}]}"
}
```

where extra array added with name "d"

i want simple array as follow

```
{"resultsets":[{"id":1,"value":"ABC","info":"ABC"},{"id":2,"value":"JKL","info":"JKL"},{"id":3,"value":"GSG","info":"DYU"}]}
```

Comment: Complete Method as Follow
`code`
[WebMethod]
        public static string GetHelloword()
        {

            string json;

            json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
            {
                resultsets = new List<Result>()
                    {
                        new Result { id = 1, value = "ABC", info = "ABC" },
                        new Result { id = 2, value = "JKL", info = "JKL" },
                        new Result { id = 3, value = "GSG", info = "DYU" }
                    }
            });

            return json;
        }

Comment: look on link below it works, maybe you missed something in your question? https://dotnetfiddle.net/ma2Ygq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to prevent direct script execution:

Suppose you were returning a plain array. The following is not a valid JS-statement:

```
{"d": [1]}
```

whereas this is:

```
[1]
```

You can find more information here:

http://encosia.com/a-breaking-change-between-versions-of-aspnet-ajax/#comment-34045